# What is name server of my domain, pointing to hosted site on Github Pages?

Tags: domain-name-system, github

I've got one domain name and I want to set it up for my hosted site on [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com/) service. In the documentation this point is mentioned that

> If you are using a top-level domain like *example.com*, you must use an
> A record pointing to *204.232.175.78*.

But my domain registrar doesn't permit me to add a DNS Record. But only asks me to fill one table like this:

> Name Server (NS Record)
>
> Server Name ......... | Server IP
>
> ns53.parsihost.com | 94.232.173.52
>
> ns2.parsihost.com | 206.223.171.254

I asked the registrar about this problem and they said to me "You must put Github's name server in those cells". So, what is the mapping from this table to DNS Records, and what is your advice for filling this kind of table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registrar gave you incorrect information. Presumably, they misunderstood and thought that Github was providing you with name service. In fact, you can't put Github's name server in those cells, they must refer to *your* nameservers, that is, the nameservers of whoever is providing you name service. That appears to be `parsihost.com`. If `parsihost.com` is providing you with name service, then you must configure their nameservers to provide the DNS records you wish for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

That's setting the authoritative DNS servers for your domain - you don't want to change that.

Given that those entries are pointing to name servers that are presumably owned by the same registrar, it would seem that they offer a DNS service.  There's probably somewhere else in their administrative tools that allows you to define records within your domain.